# Get physical path from image chosen from SD card in Image view and upload to a server

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin

i have a main activity in which there is a button and Image view control. I can show the picture selected from the device storage to  Imageview. But when I try to get image  URI from Intent an error occurs.

**My button click event code**

```
 private void TakeAPicture (object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var imageIntent = new Intent ();
            imageIntent.SetType ("image/*");
            imageIntent.SetAction (Intent.ActionGetContent);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select Image"),0);
}
```

**OnActivityresult  override  code**

```
protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {   
            base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Result.Ok) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.GetData();// code to get URI and  I am stuck here 
                string selectedImagePath = ImageFilePath.getPath(context, selectedImageUri);            
                var imageView =
                    FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView1);

                UploadImage (selectedImagePath);


            }
```

**Complete error text**

```
Error CS1061: 'Android.Content.Intent' does not contain a definition for 'GetData' and no extension method 'GetData' accepting a first argument of type 'Android.Content.Intent' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Capture)
```

Why I am getting this error. Is there no method called GetData() in Android intent or am I missing any specific library ?

Comment: its small 'g' Try this  `data.getData()`

Comment: still the same error :-(

Answer (score 2):

onButtonclick() ;-

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, SELECT_FILE);
```

onActivityResult();-

```
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };


                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);

                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
```

Comment: Actually when i tried intent.Data instead of intent.getData() the error was resolved

Answer (score 1):

You can get Complete Path using this-

```
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(
            selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    picturePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typical pattern in Xamarin where it maps Android Java components getter to C# get only (set not implemented) property.

In your case, Java code android.content.Intent.getData is mapped to C# property of Intent.Data as follows:

```
namespace Android.Content
{
    [Register ("android/content/Intent", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
    public class Intent : Object, IParcelable, ICloneable, IJavaObject, IDisposable

        public virtual Uri Data {
            [Register ("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;", "GetGetDataHandler")] ...
```

You'll also find other Java getters such as getComponent is mapped to the property of "Component" as follow:

```
        public virtual ComponentName Component {
        [Register ("getComponent", "()Landroid/content/ComponentName;", "GetGetComponentHandler")]
        get {
            if (Intent.id_getComponent == IntPtr.Zero) {
                Intent.id_getComponent = JNIEnv.GetMethodID (Intent.class_ref, "getComponent", "()Landroid/content/ComponentName;");
            } ...
```

Remembering this Xamarin's Java to C# mapping pattern will help you translate Java code into C#, and avoid getting stuck :-).

If you use Xamarin studio, check Xamarin source by using Cmd+D on OSX or F12 on Windows while the caret on the word 'Intent' in your source code, it will increase your depth of understanding of how this mapping works.